# How to pivot from two columns in pandas dataframe and create a new dataframe with only one column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot, unique

I have a df =

| Region | Status | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| East | 0 | 2500 |
| East | 1 | 31 |
| West | 0 | 1532 |
| West | 1 | 25 |
| South | 0 | 1200 |
| North | 0 | 690 |
| North | 1 | 25 |

Need to convert it to df1 =

| Region | Status_0_count | Status_1_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| East | 2500 | 31 |
| West | 1532 | 25 |
| South | 1200 | 0 (NA to be converted to 0) |
| North | 690 | 25 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df = df.pivot(index='Region', columns='Status', values='Count').fillna(0)
df.columns =[f"Status_{c}_count" for c in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
```

[`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

> Fill NA/NaN values using the specified method.